# How to get logs from azure container app?

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I have an Azure Container App with simple nodeJs api service. I need to read logs of this application, just to see my console.log('Hi there!').

Container App has Monitoring Logs with huge list of different queries. Which one I need to use to see my console? Or can some one provide a simple query to fetch my logs?

p.s. I want to see same logs which I can see with command:

```
az container logs show -n <containerName> -g <resource group>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce the issue by deploying a sample app and app service container in Azure.

To view our application console logs go to ***Revision Management***-->*click on your app*-->select ***console logs***(view details) as shown in below image:

[image]

[image]

After running the query above you can see the console logs which were generated by your application.

Comment: This means I have to create a new revision every time I want to see the log right? Is it possible to get the container running log without having to create a new provision?

Comment: How long are these logs preserved? are the preserved if the container restarts?